# Dynamic allocation of array of a struct type

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a problem in adding an element (a struct) in a dynamic array which is in a struct.

Here the main struct

```
struct testfw_t
{
    char* program;
    int timeout;
    char *logfile;
    char *cmd;
    bool silent;
    bool verbose;
    struct testTab *tests;
};
```

Here the array

```
struct testTab 
{
    int size;
    struct test_t  *oneTest;        
};
```

and at last the element to add:

```
struct test_t
{
    char *suite;        /**< suite name */
    char *name;         /**< test name */
    testfw_func_t func; /**< test function */
};
```

So I have to add a `struct test_t` in the array `testTab` in the `struct testfw_t` and I am lost in a lot of `malloc` and `realloc` calls.

PS : The init of the main struct if it can be useful which works:

```
struct testfw_t *testfw_init(char *program, int timeout, char *logfile, char *cmd, bool silent, bool verbose){

    struct testfw_t *t;
    t = malloc(sizeof(struct testfw_t));

    t->program = program;
    t->timeout = timeout;
    t->logfile = logfile;
    t->cmd = cmd;
    t->silent = silent;
    t->verbose = verbose;
    t->tests = malloc(sizeof(struct testTab));
    t->tests->size=0;
    t->tests->oneTest=NULL;

    return t;
}
```

EDIT : What I am trying

```
struct test_t *nouveau;

nouveau->suite = suite;
nouveau->name = name;
nouveau->func=func;

//fw->tests=realloc(fw->tests->oneTest,(fw->tests->size+1) * sizeof(struct testTab));

fw->tests->oneTest=malloc((fw->tests->size+1) * sizeof(nouveau));

fw->tests->oneTest[fw->tests->size+1] = *nouveau;   
fw->tests->size++;

return nouveau;
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You say you need a `testTab` array, but you only allocate one element. And you set `oneTest` to `NULL` instead of doing a `malloc`. So what/where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Where is the array supposed to be? You have a `size` field in `testTab`, but the name `oneTest` implies that it should just point to a single test, not an array.

Comment: Are the `testTab`s different for each `testfw_t`? Then it might be better to make `tests` a struct, not a pointer to a struct. (You can do it as you have shown, but it is one more alloc/free to keep track of.)

Comment: I set oneTest to NULL because on the start i have 0 test I have to add them after. The problem is that i don''t know how to add a new element in the array

Comment: I name it oneTest because it the actual element when you do fw->tests->oneTest[k]

Comment: Yes they are different.

Comment: When you add an element, increase `size` and `realloc` accordingly. (`realloc` on `NULL` behaves like `malloc`.) The name `oneTest` is misleading, because this is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array that will hold all your tests.

Comment: @MOehm I have tried but  it doesn't work see the Edit of the post. Yes sorry i dind'nt see it like that

Comment: `nouveau` doesn't point anywhere, yo you cannot dereference it with `->`. Allocate first, then do `nouveau = &fw->tests->oneTest[fw->tests->size+1]`, then assign the values to `nouveau->x`. (But you probably better copy the strings with `strdup`.)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `nouveau` doesn't point anywhere when you access it with `->`. That's undefined behaviour.

Instead, just make the array larger with `realloc` and then assign to the last element:

```
// make array larger by one
fw->tests->oneTest = realloc(fw->tests->oneTest,
                     (fw->tests->size + 1) * sizeof(struct testTab));

// to do: test success

// assign values to new slot
fw->tests->oneTest[fw->tests->size]->suite = strdup(suite);
fw->tests->oneTest[fw->tests->size]->name = strdup(name);
fw->tests->oneTest[fw->tests->size]->func = func;

// increase the array size
fw->tests->size++;
```

This is allocation code that cannot recover old data after allocation failure. The only useful thing to do on failure is to exit with an error. Jonathan Leffler points out that this can be avoided by allocating to a temporary pointer first and recover the old data when allocation fails. (Of course, you still have to decide what to do in such cases.)

I've used the (non-standard, but widely available) function `strdup` here to copy the strings' contents. Your variant works if the strings are guaranteed to "live" as long as your structure and are different or if the are literals, but usually it is better to store copies.

Comment: Are you sure about assigning the reallocated `fw->tests->oneTest` to `fw->tests` rather than `fw->tests->oneTest` (or, better, to a temporary location that can be tested for an allocation failure before overwriting valuable pointers)?

Comment: No, that's a huge blunder, of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have tried your awser and that getting better thanks to you but i have a segmentation fault. Do i have to realloc fw too because i have malloc it in the init ?

Comment: And what do you mean by test success?

Comment: By "test success" I mean that you should check whether `fw->tests->oneTest` is `NULL` and if so, do something, for example `exit(1)` the program with an appropriate message. As for your segmentation fault: Find out where it occors in a debugger or with a memory checker such as Valgrind, then look for `NULL` poiters or out-of-range accesses to arrays.

Comment: Ahhhh okay i see. But for the test i don't have access to the main and its compile on a server and i don't have the access neither

Comment: But you can write, compile and debug your program locally, no? Develop on your machine, then copy the code on the server.

Comment: No we have to do a framework but we don't have the program which test it